# Error al Parsear Fecha Sqlite

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, parsear

Estoy tratando de parsear una fecha en SQLite pero me da el siguiente error:

> W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Feb 27 00:00:00 EST 2016" (at offset 0)
>   07-15 13:32:55.178 10245-10245/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)

Les adjunto el código de mi consulta donde me truena

```
public ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ObtenerCXCPDetalle() throws ParseException {
    //DateFormat DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ArrayDetalle = new ArrayList<CXCPDetalle>();
    Cursor aRs = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA + " WHERE " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente + " = " + O_Cliente.getCliente()  , null);
    if (aRs.getCount() > 0){
        while (aRs.moveToNext())
        {
            CXCPDetalle detalleCxP = new CXCPDetalle(
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Folio))),
                    (dateFormat.parse(aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Fecha)))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Documento))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DocumentoDescripcion))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_MOneda))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Importe))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Descuento))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IEPS))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IVA))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SAldo))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldovencido))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Parcialidad))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ParcialidadTotal))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_PagoCondicionDescripcion))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_UltimoCobroObservacion))));
            ArrayDetalle.add(detalleCxP);
        }
    }

    aRs.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayDetalle;
}
```

Adjunto mi insert de los datos

```
public void InsertarCXCPDetalle(
        int Id,
        String Folio,
        Date Fecha,
        int Documento,
        String DocumentoDescripcion,
        int Cliente,
        int Moneda,
        double Importe,
        double Descuento,
        double SubTotal,
        double Retencion1,
        double Retencion2,
        double IEPS,
        double IVA,
        double Total,
        double Saldo,
        double SaldoVencido,
        String Parcialidad,
        double ParcialidadTotal,
        String PagoCondicionDescripcion,
        String UltimoCobroObservacion
)
{
    Object [] CXCPDetalle = {Id,
                          Folio,
                          Fecha,
                          Documento,
                          DocumentoDescripcion,
                          Cliente,
                          Moneda,
                          Importe,
                          Descuento,
                          SubTotal,
                          Retencion1,
                          Retencion2,
                          IEPS,
                          IVA,
                          Total,
                          Saldo,
                          SaldoVencido,
                          Parcialidad,
                          ParcialidadTotal,
                          PagoCondicionDescripcion,
                          UltimoCobroObservacion};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA + " Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", CXCPDetalle);
}
```

Aclaro que los datos que obtengo para llenar la base de datos los obtengo desde un webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el formato el cual le debes aplicar

```
DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

Y convertirlo a `String` o a `Date` de acuerdo a tus necesidades

Comment: Hurtado deja probar, gracias

Comment: @HugoRodriguez si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar tu problema, deberías marcarla como aceptada haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda de la misma.